# CMake libraries build order

Tags: cmake, sdl-2

I have an Android Studio project with the following structure:

```
 -jni
   --src
   --SDL2
   --SDL_mixer_X
```

jni/CMakeLists.txt has:

```
project(GAME)
add_subdirectory(SDL2)
add_subdirectory(SDL_mixer_X)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

jni/src/CMakeLists.txt has:

```
project(app)
find_package(SDL2)
find_package(SDL_mixer_X)
...
target_link_library(app SDL2 SDL_mixer_X)
...
```

SDL2 and SDL_mixer_X both have own CMakeLists.txt files that should not be modified.
SDL_mixer_X depends on SDL2, because it needs libSDL2.so.

When I compile my project, CMake firstly tries to build SDL_mixer_X and fails, because SDL2 hasn't been built yet. Please, tell me, how could I force CMake to build SDL_mixer_X strictly after building SDL2.

Addition:
SDL_mixer_X has a dependency, libtimidity-sdl, that looks for compiled libSDL2.so library and fails to build (because SDL2 isn't built yet)

P.S. I've seen some solutions with add_library(), but as far as I've understood SDL2 and SDL_mixer aren't designed to be included that way.

Comment: "When I compile my project, CMake firstly tries to build SDL_mixer_X and fails, because SDL2 hasn't been built yet." - This is actually **vague** description of the problem, since it can designate different problems, each required separate solution. Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**.

Comment: SDL_mixer_X has a dependency, libtimidity-sdl, that looks for compiled libSDL2.so library and fails to build (because SDL2 isn't built yet)

Comment: I just have to build SDL2 before SDL_mixer_X (and  before libtimidity-sdl, as a consequence)

Comment: There are **several stages** of processing the project. The first stage is **configuration**: at that stage all `CMakeLists.txt` are processed and CMake defines rules for building one files from others. The second stage - **build** - actually builds those files by calling compiler and linker when needed. You haven't provide the error message, so we can only **guess**, which stage causes the error. I would assume it is **configuration** stage (NOT when you "compile your project"): when being *configured*, `SDL_mixer_X` expects SDL2 to have **already** been **built**. Is my guessing correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: So you need to process `jni/SDL_mixer_X/CMakeLists.txt` only after SDL2 is already built. You cannot achieve that by ordering `add_subdirectory` calls, which affects only on **configuration order**, and cannot achieve that by `add_dependencies`, which affects only on **build order**. You need to do following steps in order: 1. Configure (`cmake`) SDL, 2. Build (`make`) SDL. 3. Install (`make install`) SDL. 4. Configure SDL_mixer_X. 5. Build SDL_mixer_X. 6. Install SDL_mixer_X. Only after that you may configure the project under `src`.

Comment: Hmm. But how could I achieve this in Android Studio?

Comment: CMake has commands for "general" scripting. E.g. `execute_process` immediately executes given program, so using it you could call `cmake` and `make`. But I unsure whether it would work for Android Studio. Otherwise, you need to just sequentially process in Android Studio all 3 projects: Load `SDL` project, build and install it. Then load `SDL_mixer_X` project, build and install it. Then load the project under `src`.